# Value of column in next row

Tags: sql-server

```
FromDate        ToDate        TempDate
2011-05-03      2011-08-02    NULL
2011-06-03      2011-08-02    2011-05-03
2007-09-30      2009-09-30    2011-06-03
```

I have a table in SQL Server and want to have column `TempDate` have the value of the previous row's `FromDate`

Comment: A table in SQL has no notion of order, therefore you cannot reference the "next row".

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE tab SET
    Tempdate = (SELECT Max(FromDate) 
                FROM Tab t2 
                WHERE t2.Fromdate < tab.FromDate )
```

Comment: does Update tab tb <-- aliasing possible??

Comment: @brykneval if this is not desired, you should refine you understanding of "preceding FromDate"

Comment: I just solved it using temp table, is it okay?? I hope we have performace boost regarding use of temp table rather than updating every row